Пропуск столбца при выполнении LOAD DATA INFILE
Есть файл 1.txt:  30,high,0,12 11,low,1,32 42,high,0,11 ...Кол-во столбцов в строке файла совпадает с кол-вом столбцов в таблице mySql. И использую запрос: 'LOAD DATA INFILE "/var/1.txt" INTO TABLE data FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'(id,level,hand,type)'  Это работает. Но мне нужно сделать ещё одну вставку из этого же файла (другим запросом) в другую таблицу, где нет столбца "level". Возможно ли как-то заставить его игнорировать второе значение строки из файла? Можно изменить структуру файла (формирую я его), чтобы он удовлетворял этим двум запросам сразу.

...'(id,@dummy,hand,type)'

@Akina то что нужно. Спасибо! dummy - зарезервированное слово в mysql?))

dummy - зарезервированное слово в mysql? Конечно, нет. Может, вы хотя бы сейчас найдёте время на то, чтобы почитать документацию?

@Akina я же юморнул так. dummy в прямом переводе "дурачок" же
